Solving a 1st-order PDE with two variables using method of characteristics
I'm trying to solve the following PDE
$$ xu_x +yu_y = 2x $$
with the boundary condition $ u(x,x^2) = x $.
So I start with change of parameters
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = x \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{x} dx = dt $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = y \quad \rightarrow \quad \frac{1}{y} dy = dt $$
Integrating those gives (and applying boundary condition:
$$ x = g(s) \cdot e^t $$
$$ y = f(s) \cdot e^t = g^2(s) \cdot e^t$$
Now I rewrite the left hand side of the PDE using chain rule:
$$ xu_x + yu_y = x \frac{du}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx} + y \frac{du}{dt} \frac{dt}{dy} = $$
$$ = x \frac{du}{dt} \frac{g(s)}{x} + y \frac{du}{dt} \frac{g^2(s)}{y} = g(s) \frac{du}{dt} + g^2(s) \frac{du}{dt} $$
Setting all of this toghether
$$ g(s) \frac{du}{dt} + g^2(s) \frac{du}{dt} = 2x = 2 g(s) \cdot e^t $$
$$ \longrightarrow \frac{du}{dt} = \frac{2e^t}{1+g(s)} $$
Solving this ODE gives
$$ u(s,t) = \frac{2}{1+g(s)}\cdot e^t + q(s) $$
And here I get stuck because clearly I did something wrong but I can't see it! Any tips?

General solution: $u(x,y)=2\cdot x+f! \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$
Boundary condition: $u(x,x^2)=x \implies f(x)=-x$
Finally: $u(x,y)=2 x-\frac{y}{x}$

@gpmath how did you get this general solution?

Build the Lagrange-Charpit equations:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x, \frac{dy}{dt}=y, \frac{du}{dt}=2x$$
With the solution:
$$x(t)=c_2 e^t,; y(t)=c_3 e^t,; u(t)=2c_2 e^t+c_1=2\cdot x(t)+c_1=2\cdot x(t)+f \left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)} \right)$$

@gpmath Ahh I see! Appreciate the help sir:))

Your mistake is made when you took $g = f^2$ because of the boundary condition. Indeed, the latter has to be applied to $u$ only at the end, otherwise the variable $y$ is constrained to coincide with $x^2$ permanently.
Gpmath gave you the final solution in his comments; here is the procedure to derive this result. Starting from the Lagrange-Charpit equations, i.e.
$$
\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2x},
$$
one deduces straightforwardly from the first two equations that $x(t) = Ae^t$ and $y(t) = Be^t$, where $A$ and $B$ are constant (with respect to $t$), while the last equation, namely $\dot{u}(t) = 2x(t) = 2Ae^t$, yields $u(t) = 2Ae^t + C$, with $C$ another constant of integration.
Now, we would like to switch back to the initial variables; in other words, we need to express the solution $u(t)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ again by substituting the variable $t$ and the constants of integration. The quantity $Ae^t$ is simply replaced by $x$, while the constant $C$ must be an arbitrary expression of $x$ and $y$ independent of $t$, as said before. Since the quantity $\frac{x}{y} = \frac{A}{B}$ doesn't depend on $t$, you can set $C = f(\frac{x}{y})$, with $f$ an arbitrary function.
In consequence, the solution is $u(x,y) = 2x + f(\frac{x}{y})$. Now it is time to apply the given boundary condition in order to determine $f$ : one has $u(x,x^2) = 2x + f(\frac{1}{x}) = x$, hence $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}$ and finally $u(x,y) = 2x - \frac{y}{x}$.

Oh I see what I did now! Thank you so much for the clarification sir!:)
